# Why can't spacy differentiate between two homograph tokens in the following code?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, spacy, word-embedding

A homograph is a word that has the same spelling as another word but has a different sound and a different meaning, for example,**lead** *(to go in front of)* / **lead** *(a metal)* .

I was trying to use spacy word vectors to compare documents with each other by summing each word vector for each document and then finally finding cosine similarity. If for example spacy vectors have the same vector for the two **'lead'** listed above , the results will be probably bad.

In the code below , why does the similarity between the two **'bank'**
tokens come out as **1.00** ?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

str1 = 'The guy went inside the bank to take out some money'
str2 = 'The house by the river bank.'

str1_tokenized = nlp(str1.decode('utf8'))
str2_tokenized = nlp(str2.decode('utf8'))

token1 = str1_tokenized[-6]
token2 = str2_tokenized[-2]

print 'token1 =  {}  token2 = {}'.format(token1,token2)

print token1.similarity(token2)
```

The output for given program is

> token1 =  bank  token2 = bank
>
> 1.0

Comment: From spaCy : **Identical tokens are obviously 100% similar to each other. Similarity is determined by comparing word vectors, multi-dimensional meaning representations of a word.** What you are trying to do is finding similarity according to word senses, sense2vec might be useful since it takes token's POS-tags into account.

Answer (score 4):

As kntgu already pointed out, spaCy distinguishes tokens by their characters, not by their semantic meaning. The sense2vec approach by the developers of spaCy concatenates tokens with their POS-tag and can help in the case of 'lead_VERB' vs. 'lead_NOUN'. However, it will not help in your example of 'bank (river bank)' vs. 'bank (financial institute)', as both are nouns.

SpaCy does not support any solution to this out of the box, but you can have a look at contextualized word representations like ELMo or BERT. Both generate word vectors for a given sentence, taking the context into account. Therefore, I assume the vectors for both 'bank' tokens will be substantially different. 
Both are relatively recent approaches and are not as comfortable to use, but might help in your use case. For ELMo, there is a command line tool which lets you generate word embeddings for a set of sentences without having to write any code: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/tutorials/how_to/elmo.md#writing-contextual-representations-to-disk